# fatal error 'GL/glx.h' file not found #include <GL/glx.h> after xquartz is already installed

Tags: c++, opengl, xquartz

When i run the program i get the following error

fatal error: 'Gl/glx.h' file not found

I am attempting to run a c++ xll graphics program on my mac. I have already downloaded Xquartz and used it to run multiple graphics programs on my computer and now i am trying to figure out what i'm missing in order to get this program to run. if anybody can point me in the right direction it would be wonderful!

Thanks

here is a copy of the make file provided

```
  1 ## If you receive XRR errors, include -lXrandr option on LFLAGS line
  2 all: atrace
  3 ##LIB    = ./libggfonts.so
  4 LIB    = ./libggfonts.a
  5 LFLAGS = -L -lX11 -lGLU -lGL -lm #-lXrandr
  6 CFLAGS = -O2 -Wall -Wextra -I
  7 SOURCE = atrace.cpp init.cpp scene.cpp render.cpp sphere.cpp ppm.cpp      log.cpp \
  8 vector.cpp input.cpp files.cpp perlin.cpp texture.cpp divide.cpp \
  9 cubemap.cpp matrix.cpp fresnel.cpp haze.cpp animate.cpp \
  10 photons.cpp subsurf.cpp
  11 
  12 #all: atrace atrace.o init.o scene.o render.o sphere.o ppm.o log.o \
  13 #       vector.o input.o files.o perlin.o texture.o divide.o \
  14 #       cubemap.o matrix.o fresnel.o haze.o animate.o
  15 #
  16 #atrace: $(SOURCE) fonts.h defs.h ppm.h extern.h bvh.h animate.h $(LIB)
  17 #       g++ $(CFLAGS) $(SOURCE) $(LFLAGS) $(LIB) -o atrace
  18 
  19 atrace: atrace.o init.o scene.o render.o sphere.o ppm.o log.o \
  20 vector.o input.o files.o perlin.o texture.o divide.o \
  21 cubemap.o matrix.o fresnel.o haze.o animate.o photons.o subsurf.o \
  22 defs.h ppm.h extern.h bvh.h animate.h
  23         g++ atrace.o init.o scene.o render.o sphere.o ppm.o log.o vector.o \
  24 input.o files.o perlin.o texture.o divide.o cubemap.o matrix.o fresnel.o \
  25 haze.o animate.o photons.o subsurf.o $(LIB) -oatrace $(LFLAGS)
  26 
  27 
  28 atrace.o: atrace.cpp defs.h ppm.h extern.h bvh.h animate.h
  29         g++ atrace.cpp -c $(CFLAGS) $(LFLAGS)
  30 init.o: init.cpp defs.h
  31         g++ init.cpp -c $(CFLAGS) $(LFLAGS)
  32 scene.o: scene.cpp defs.h
  33         g++ scene.cpp -c $(CFLAGS) $(LFLAGS)
  34 render.o: render.cpp defs.h
  35         g++ render.cpp -c $(CFLAGS) $(LFLAGS)
  36 sphere.o: sphere.cpp defs.h
  37         g++ sphere.cpp -c $(CFLAGS) $(LFLAGS)
  38 ppm.o: ppm.cpp defs.h ppm.h
  39         g++ ppm.cpp -c $(CFLAGS) $(LFLAGS)
  40 log.o: log.cpp defs.h
  41         g++ log.cpp -c $(CFLAGS) $(LFLAGS)
  42 vector.o: vector.cpp defs.h
  43         g++ vector.cpp -c $(CFLAGS) $(LFLAGS)
  44 input.o: input.cpp defs.h
  45         g++ input.cpp -c $(CFLAGS) $(LFLAGS)
  46 files.o: files.cpp defs.h files.h
  47         g++ files.cpp -c $(CFLAGS) $(LFLAGS)
  48 perlin.o: perlin.cpp defs.h
  49         g++ perlin.cpp -c $(CFLAGS) $(LFLAGS)
  50 texture.o: texture.cpp defs.h
  51         g++ texture.cpp -c $(CFLAGS) $(LFLAGS)
  52 divide.o: divide.cpp defs.h bvh.h
  53         g++ divide.cpp -c $(CFLAGS) $(LFLAGS)
  54 cubemap.o: cubemap.cpp defs.h
  55         g++ cubemap.cpp -c $(CFLAGS) $(LFLAGS)
  56 matrix.o: matrix.cpp defs.h
  57         g++ matrix.cpp -c $(CFLAGS) $(LFLAGS)
  58 fresnel.o: fresnel.cpp defs.h
  59         g++ fresnel.cpp -c $(CFLAGS) $(LFLAGS)
  60 haze.o: haze.cpp defs.h
  61         g++ haze.cpp -c $(CFLAGS) $(LFLAGS)
  62 animate.o: animate.cpp defs.h animate.h ppm.h
  63         g++ animate.cpp -c $(CFLAGS) $(LFLAGS)
  64 photons.o: photons.cpp defs.h
  65         g++ photons.cpp -c $(CFLAGS) $(LFLAGS)
  66 subsurf.o: subsurf.cpp defs.h
  67         g++ subsurf.cpp -c $(CFLAGS) $(LFLAGS)
  68 
  69 clean:
  70         rm -f atrace
  71         rm -f *.o
```

Comment: Your program fails compile; that's the major culörit

Comment: sorry this, program does compile this is just the make file please don't comment endless you are absolutly sure you know whats wrong

Comment: _"if anybody can point me in the right direction it would be wonderful!"_ Did you install that library correctly and successfully  at your environment?

Comment: yes this program is a atrace graphics program that runs on linux machines. i have ran this program many times on my school computers but at home i only have a mac OS so i was told to download xquartz. On another thread i ask this same question and got an answer that seemed to have worked i added -I/opt/X11/include and link with the options -L/opt/X11/lib -lGL -lX11. to Cflags and Lflags now im getting the clockrealtime is a undeclared identifier. I just need to know how to complie openGL Xorg and linux programs on MAC OS

Comment: Downloading is probably not enough.

Comment: Yes i understand that once i added what i was told on another thread it took care of the fatal error it just gave me a error: use of undeclared identifier "CLOCK_REALTIME" clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &timerend); i read that this function is not supported on mac OS so i guess i will start a new thread to see if anyone can help me figure out how to implement this on a MAC OS